# How to play video in video view in Android?

Tags: android, video

I am trying to play video which is encoded video in H264 encoding scheme. Video is in HD(High resolution). When I play the video of low resolution it play fine but when i play high the resolution video then it shows error *sorry video cannot be played*.

I want to play high resolution video file in my video view and i know its possible because in android there are some video player which can run this type of files so why not mine?

So please tell a solution and I'm not interested to open my video in *action intent* which opens installed video player in the device. I want to run HD videos in my video view and I have used the code below, but it doesn't work-

```
videoMediaController = new MediaController(this);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
videoView.setVideoPath(url);
videoMediaController.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
videoView.setMediaController(videoMediaController);
videoView.requestFocus();
videoView.start();
```

Comment: Does your phone support playing HD Videos??

Comment: no my phone doesnot support hd video but i have qq player which run hd video in slow rate. so how that palyer paly hd video which is not play in media player

Comment: Android Supported Media Formats http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: i know all media format in android.video is mp4  but in high defination(HD).

Comment: Your video is most likely not encoded to be compatible with the built in hardware encoder, and the reason your other third party players can handle it, is because they are not playing it with Androids video player but instead they use their own software codecs.

Comment: @chrkad so why that player run in my os(android) because in android os only those application run which built in their framework. so please explain this in detail

Comment: In default player, will you able to play?

Comment: @robinhood default player not run hd video

Comment: Then you will never get it to play with the android API code either. You need to write your own codecs and software (or use something like ffmpeg), and bypass the android api videoplayer.

Comment: what is the device of this qq player? i have some problems to play video in my app on Samsung devices!it seems samsung didn't integrate the same videoplayer than the others